# why await does not wait untill httpclient postasync complets?

Tags: c#, async-await, xmlhttprequest, httpclient, httpresponse

Im creating http client for consume some api.

Here is my client method calling to api endpoint.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequestAsync()
        {

            string adaptiveUri = "https://some-api/api/Authentication/AuthenticateThirdPartyUserAsync";

            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { userName = "uname", password = "123", applicantCode = "hello" });
                var payload = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
                try
                {
                    responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(adaptiveUri, payload);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (responseMessage == null)
                    {
                        responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
                    }
                    responseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("RestHttpClient.SendRequest failed: {0}", ex);
                }
                return responseMessage;
            }
        }
```

calling method is as follows

```
public async Task<IBaseStatus> Handle(InspectionAddedEvent domainEvent)
{
   var tk = await _iAClient.SendRequestAsync();
   return something;
}
```

but `await` does not wait untill postasync completes.

but when i use

```
httpClient.PostAsync(adaptiveUri, payload).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

it waits until post is complets.

can anyone have idea about this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't wait till it completes? How do you know it doesn't complete?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guide on posting code and [edit] the question to show all necessary code to reproduce the error behavior - the one shown in the post so far is standard code to make async calls and there is no reason to believe it to behave the way you described. You may want to completely remove all exception handling (unless it is where your synchronous path comes in - i.e. invalid DNS name can make this code to fail synchronously)

Answer (score 1):

`await _iAClient.SendRequestAsync();` definitely waits for the `PostAsync`.

I think the problem is that your are receiving an exception in `SendRequestAsync` and confuse the result.

Remove completely the `try/carch` block

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequestAsync()
{
    string adaptiveUri ="https://someapi/api/Authentication/AuthenticateThirdPartyUserAsync";

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { userName = "uname", password = "123", applicantCode = "hello" });
        var payload = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return await httpClient.PostAsync(adaptiveUri, payload);                
    }
}
```

And try to catch it in the caller:

```
public async Task<IBaseStatus> Handle(InspectionAddedEvent domainEvent)
{
    try 
    {
        var tk = await _iAClient.SendRequestAsync();
        return something;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Probably return some IBaseStatus
    }       
}
```

Comment: No chance, im calling from static class is that effect to await?